# How to output to clipboard

Tags: powershell

I have a GUI listview with 3 columns (FullRowSelect enabled) 
With a Copy button, that I want to copy the 3 columns of each row into the clipboard, so that there is a new line for each row.

But what happens is I get the 3 columns of each row joined together in one string.

NB the Write-Host's are just there to help me see what's going on, this is part of a no console GUI app in PowerShell

I've tried piping $output via Out-String | clip and others, but always get the same result of the whole lot being in one line.
I'm sure this is probably something very simple ! my PS skills are just basic !
Please can someone point me in the right direction :)

```
Function Copy2ClipBoard {

    foreach ($line in $OutputlistView.SelectedItems) { 

        $allitems = ($line.SubItems[0].Text + " , " + $line.SubItems[1].Text + " , " + $line.SubItems[2].Text)
        $Output += $allitems
        Write-Host $allitems

    }
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host $Output
    [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($Output)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will only work in PowerShell 5.x, since PowerShell 6 doesn't offer this cmdlet ...

You can use the [´Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

```
Function Copy2ClipBoard {

# Clear the clipboard
Set-Clipboard
foreach ($line in $OutputlistView.SelectedItems) { 

    $allitems = ($line.SubItems[0].Text + " , " + $line.SubItems[1].Text + " , " + $line.SubItems[2].Text)
    $Output += $allitems
    Set-Clipboard -Value $allitems -Append
    Write-Host $allitems

}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host $Output
}
```

You can check the clipboard via `Get-Clipboard`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not like with `clip`.

> but always get the same result of the whole lot being in one line.

That is because you are just building a progressively longer string and **not** an array as you seem to think. When you do `$Output += $allitems` you are just adding the `$allitems` string to `$output` with a space in between. [Moerwalds solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201152/3829407) skirts around this by using the `-Append` parameter of `Set-Clipboard`.

In reality you could just deal with your input string in one of a few ways. Simplest would be piping into clip, you could also use something like `` -join "`r`n" ``

```
$OutputlistView.SelectedItems | Foreach-Object{
    $_.SubItems[0].Text + " , " + $_.SubItems[1].Text + " , " + $_.SubItems[2].Text
} | clip
```